# Unable to run pre-installation script /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, dpkg

I try to install some program in Docker, but get:

preinst /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst install
The requested cluster does not exist and cluster creation is not supported.
dpkg: error processing archive arch.deb (--install):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
postrm /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm abort-install

The Docker container is created FROM ubuntu:14.04

The code I use in Dockerfile is:

```
RUN sudo ./dir/install.sh
```

This code works fine on Ubuntu 14.04 directly, but not in Docker. Any thoughts? Do I need to install/add something extra first?

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you...

Comment: @IgnacioAra sure, just there is not much to add: RUN sudo ./dir/install.sh

Comment: Your code appears to be incomplete. If we try to run the same command, it says dir doesn't exist. Please see [mcve]

Comment: @BMitch the folder is created by untarring an archive that I cannot provide. I was hoping that someone could tell me how to debug such problems in dpkg.